# how can i install new themes on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, themes

I want to install this but i have no idea how to do it.
http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/X-Aero+%28XFWM4+Windows+7+%2B+Vista+Theme%29?content=170901
Can anyone give me a sep-by-step please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Download X-Aero theme**

Open your terminal and run following command :

```
wget http://xfce-look.org/CONTENT/content-files/170901-x-aero.zip
```

**2. Extract the theme**

```
cd Downloads/ && unzip 170901-x-aero.zip
```

**3. Copy all theme folder to /usr/share/themes**

First, open Thunar as root :

```
gksudo thunar
```

Select all X-Aero theme folder in `Downloads/` Directory

[image]

Paste it to `/usr/share/themes` directory.

**4. Open your theme setting**

Go to Setting --> Appearance and you'll see many themes with X-Aeros name, click on one of them.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot copy it to usr/share/themes. :/

Comment: open a terminal and type gksu nautilus on it, then you'll be able to copy it

Comment: @Rockloh i updated my answer

Comment: Click check-mark near my answer

Comment: `sudo tar -xzf 170901-X-Aero.tar.gz -C /usr/share/themes/` should also work, but Appearance didn't update whereas Window Manager settings did. The window button icons are missing though.

Answer (score 1):

I see they only offer a tar.gz file now, for which the accepted steps don't work. This worked for me, select all lines and shift+insert paste it into your terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -N https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1460766502/170901-X-Aero.tar.gz
cd /usr/share/themes
sudo tar -xzf ~/Downloads/170901-X-Aero.tar.gz
sudo chmod -R 755 X-Aero*
sudo chmod -R 644 X-Aero*/xfwm4/*
```

That will download any newer version and fix the permissions. You will manually have to go to Settings, Window Manager to select one of the X-Areo themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and extract theme to `.themes` directory in you user's home directory in such way that you should have following path:

`~/.themes/XAeroThemeName/[xfwm4 folder from the theme should be here]`.

If you want to try some other themes on xubuntu then for start you can use the script below that downloads few additional themes and puts them to `~/.themes/` directory. After that you can go to `Settings -> Appearance` and to `Settings -> Window Manager` and choose one of downloaded themes from there.

```
cd ~
mkdir .themes
cd .themes

wget https://github.com/paullinuxthemer/Prof-XFCE-theme/archive/b67f65a2d0ca8eb48c2537e2dcdac99858ffb5cc.zip
unzip b67f65a2d0ca8eb48c2537e2dcdac99858ffb5cc.zip
mv Prof-XFCE-theme-b67f65a2d0ca8eb48c2537e2dcdac99858ffb5cc/*/ .
rm b67f65a2d0ca8eb48c2537e2dcdac99858ffb5cc.zip
rm -r Prof-XFCE-theme-b67f65a2d0ca8eb48c2537e2dcdac99858ffb5cc/

wget https://github.com/hrdwrrsk/AdwaitaExtended/archive/e58865f7c5d0dffa334b17152c063f6cbac89faa.zip
unzip e58865f7c5d0dffa334b17152c063f6cbac89faa.zip
mv AdwaitaExtended-e58865f7c5d0dffa334b17152c063f6cbac89faa/AdwaitaEx/ .
mv AdwaitaExtended-e58865f7c5d0dffa334b17152c063f6cbac89faa/AdwaitaEx-dark/ .
rm e58865f7c5d0dffa334b17152c063f6cbac89faa.zip
rm -r AdwaitaExtended-e58865f7c5d0dffa334b17152c063f6cbac89faa/

wget https://github.com/paullinuxthemer/Alu-Night/archive/919bba4cece1e65cf846ee2f8082186a1ba10c59.zip
unzip 919bba4cece1e65cf846ee2f8082186a1ba10c59.zip
mv Alu-Night-919bba4cece1e65cf846ee2f8082186a1ba10c59/Alu-Night-straight-XFCE/ .
rm 919bba4cece1e65cf846ee2f8082186a1ba10c59.zip
rm -r Alu-Night-919bba4cece1e65cf846ee2f8082186a1ba10c59/

wget https://github.com/paullinuxthemer/Mc-OS-themes/archive/616e3b46e7ca02fde6e229cac5332e538029c4aa.zip
unzip 616e3b46e7ca02fde6e229cac5332e538029c4aa.zip
mv Mc-OS-themes-616e3b46e7ca02fde6e229cac5332e538029c4aa/McOS-CTLina-XFCE/ .
mv Mc-OS-themes-616e3b46e7ca02fde6e229cac5332e538029c4aa/McOS-CTLina-XFCE-Dark/ .
rm 616e3b46e7ca02fde6e229cac5332e538029c4aa.zip
rm -r Mc-OS-themes-616e3b46e7ca02fde6e229cac5332e538029c4aa/

wget https://github.com/paullinuxthemer/PRO-Dark-XFCE-Edition/archive/4b3f32f050f6504663a7e8f4038c33818557581a.zip
unzip 4b3f32f050f6504663a7e8f4038c33818557581a.zip
mv PRO-Dark-XFCE-Edition-4b3f32f050f6504663a7e8f4038c33818557581a/*/ .
rm 4b3f32f050f6504663a7e8f4038c33818557581a.zip
rm -r PRO-Dark-XFCE-Edition-4b3f32f050f6504663a7e8f4038c33818557581a/

wget https://github.com/paullinuxthemer/McOS-MJV-XFCE-Edition/archive/6435c3919386006bee4895da617a3a2d42c5b7ac.zip
unzip 6435c3919386006bee4895da617a3a2d42c5b7ac.zip
mv McOS-MJV-XFCE-Edition-6435c3919386006bee4895da617a3a2d42c5b7ac/*/ .
rm 6435c3919386006bee4895da617a3a2d42c5b7ac.zip
rm -r McOS-MJV-XFCE-Edition-6435c3919386006bee4895da617a3a2d42c5b7ac/

wget https://github.com/paullinuxthemer/McOS-XFCE-Edition/archive/8d90e108377e89359e69d83c83099195b6c98f10.zip
unzip 8d90e108377e89359e69d83c83099195b6c98f10.zip
mv McOS-XFCE-Edition-8d90e108377e89359e69d83c83099195b6c98f10/*/ .
rm 8d90e108377e89359e69d83c83099195b6c98f10.zip
rm -r McOS-XFCE-Edition-8d90e108377e89359e69d83c83099195b6c98f10/

wget https://github.com/mrbrownstone07/Mayu_dark_gtk_theme/archive/8f2aef56b51007100e7fb3d81ba1d86ca58a5cd2.zip
unzip 8f2aef56b51007100e7fb3d81ba1d86ca58a5cd2.zip
mv Mayu_dark_gtk_theme-8f2aef56b51007100e7fb3d81ba1d86ca58a5cd2 Mayu_dark
rm 8f2aef56b51007100e7fb3d81ba1d86ca58a5cd2.zip

wget https://github.com/tdloi/nanodesu-xfwm4/archive/b2e8d5f6a59b01e6cc36c9d0f12610264f1bdd57.zip
unzip b2e8d5f6a59b01e6cc36c9d0f12610264f1bdd57.zip
mv nanodesu-xfwm4-b2e8d5f6a59b01e6cc36c9d0f12610264f1bdd57/*/ .
rm b2e8d5f6a59b01e6cc36c9d0f12610264f1bdd57.zip
rm -r nanodesu-xfwm4-b2e8d5f6a59b01e6cc36c9d0f12610264f1bdd57/

wget https://github.com/rafacuevas3/dots-theme/archive/9dae772fe2c869548d8a6953d2b02412bdddb941.zip
unzip 9dae772fe2c869548d8a6953d2b02412bdddb941.zip
mv dots-theme-9dae772fe2c869548d8a6953d2b02412bdddb941/Dots*/ .
rm 9dae772fe2c869548d8a6953d2b02412bdddb941.zip
rm -r dots-theme-9dae772fe2c869548d8a6953d2b02412bdddb941/

wget https://github.com/dayanidi/rainyday/archive/e86d8c2a6faa6e300007a6e7eed018872a0a9bbb.zip
unzip e86d8c2a6faa6e300007a6e7eed018872a0a9bbb.zip
mv rainyday-e86d8c2a6faa6e300007a6e7eed018872a0a9bbb/*/ .
rm e86d8c2a6faa6e300007a6e7eed018872a0a9bbb.zip
rm -r rainyday-e86d8c2a6faa6e300007a6e7eed018872a0a9bbb/

wget https://github.com/ju1464/E5150_Themes/archive/91ea678f3a3c2d3af717959429eb207d0dadb0cd.zip
unzip 91ea678f3a3c2d3af717959429eb207d0dadb0cd.zip
mv E5150_Themes-91ea678f3a3c2d3af717959429eb207d0dadb0cd/GTK-Gnome/*/ .
rm 91ea678f3a3c2d3af717959429eb207d0dadb0cd.zip
rm -r E5150_Themes-91ea678f3a3c2d3af717959429eb207d0dadb0cd/

wget https://github.com/addy-dclxvi/xfwm4-theme-collections/archive/0d0f2cf18efcf121877fc48c8b2c601c2837eb07.zip
unzip 0d0f2cf18efcf121877fc48c8b2c601c2837eb07.zip
mv xfwm4-theme-collections-0d0f2cf18efcf121877fc48c8b2c601c2837eb07/*/ .
rm 0d0f2cf18efcf121877fc48c8b2c601c2837eb07.zip
rm -r xfwm4-theme-collections-0d0f2cf18efcf121877fc48c8b2c601c2837eb07/
```